# Ambiguity when using initializer list as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, initializer-list

I am puzzled by the following piece of code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

class Foo {};

void f(Eigen::MatrixXd const &) {}
void f(std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> const &) {}

void g(Foo const &) {}
void g(std::vector<Foo> const &) {}

int main()
{
    Foo a, b, c;
    Eigen::MatrixXd x, y, z;

    // f({x, y}); ambiguity, why?!
    f({x, y, z}); // ok

    g({a,b}); // ok
    g({a,b,c}); // ok
}
```

If I un-comment the 3-rd code line in `main()`, I get an ambiguous call error,

```
/Users/vlad/so.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/Users/vlad/so.cpp:17:13: error: call of overloaded 'f(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
     f({x, y}); //ambiguity, why?!
             ^
/Users/vlad/so.cpp:17:13: note: candidates are:
/Users/vlad/so.cpp:6:6: note: void f(const MatrixXd&)
 void f(Eigen::MatrixXd const &) {}
      ^
/Users/vlad/so.cpp:7:6: note: void f(const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&)
 void f(std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> const &) {}
```

Calling it with 3 items in the init list works.

However, if instead of using Eigen matrices, I use my own class `Foo` (see the function `g`), everything works fine. I have absolutely no clue why the commented line is ambiguous when using Eigen. Any ideas?

PS: If I overload `f` so that it takes a `std::initializer_list<Eigen::MatrixXd>`, then the problem disappears, no more ambiguous call.

Comment: Is `Eigen::MatrixXd` an aggregate?

Comment: @KerrekSB, not sure, probably not. Why? If I make `Foo` an aggregate by adding a POD member, nothing changes.

Comment: @KerrekSB It seems to have [constructors](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html), so no.

Comment: Correct, it is not, it is a huge class actually.

Comment: Does it compile if you do `Eigen::MatrixXd mat{x, y};`? If so, then it could do what it does for that or use the vector's list constructor.

Comment: I'm not having much luck finding a constructor for `MatrixXd` that takes two `MatrixXd` arguments, but if that exists, then you'd get an ambiguity error. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/118f706f404fc763) for a similar example.

Comment: @chris, no, it spits an error

Comment: The plot thickens...

Comment: `MatrixXd` has actually a ctor that takes 2 parameters of type `Index`, used to specify the dimension of the matrix at runtime. But that version should be rejected by the compiler, as `Index` is just a typedef for `size_t`, and there shouldn't be any ambiguity.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks much for the snippet, I understand now why an ambiguity can appear, and MatrixXd has a ctor taking 2 params, but of type `size_t`. I believe that to get the ambiguity, MatrixXd should have a ctor taking 2 MatrixXd's.

Comment: Could be [this constructor](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/ead84fa7047cab0995f71180592a001e032f1fa4/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h?at=default#cl-241). The line `Base::_check_template_params();` might be what caused errors when you attempted chris' suggestion, but that doesn't prevent overload resolution from choosing that constructor along with `vector`'s constructor. Another contrived [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aee5d96a45ae603f).

Comment: @Praetorian, Dang, I didn't see that listed in the documentation. Good catch.

Comment: @Praetorian Ahh ok, it may be the reason indeed. Thanks very much for digging in, so it seems that the reasonable solution is to just overload the function for `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @chris Took almost 15 min of digging to find it! And I didn't even see it in the doxygen docs.

Comment: @Praetorian you should post the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is most likely being caused by [this constructor template](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/ead84fa7047cab0995f71180592a001e032f1fa4/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h?at=default#cl-247).

```
template<typename T0, typename T1>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const T0& x, const T1& y)
{ ... }
```

Both that constructor and `vector`'s `initializer_list` constructor are equally good matches in the function call `f({x, y});`, leading to the ambiguity error.

[Here's a made up example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71109c19fd635816) with similar constructors and function calls that leads to an ambiguity error as well.